# IIS application pool - retry after pool identity login fails

Tags: iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

Is there a way to force an IIS application pool to continue to retry to start even if its pool identity login failed the first time?  Here is the sequence I am seeing:

1. IIS app pool is set to run as valid domain credentials
2. Machine is rebooted
3. IIS app pool attempts to start, but domain controllers cannot be contacted yet
4. IIS app pool identity logon fails
5. Event viewer shows 'WAS' event IDs 5021, 5057, 5059 in quick succession (basically errors that the app pool identity logon failed)
6. app pool is disabled and needs manual intervention to restart.
7. After short amount of time passes, app pool manual start is successful after network path to domain controllers becomes available

Comment: IIS won't retry for the application. I remembered taskscheduler can execute program based on an event. You can event delay the task. So maybe you can create a task to execute powershell every time event viwer return 5021,5057,5059 error.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found any solution or workaround?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino We had to write a custom scheduled task that runs on reboot tha that attempts to restart the app pool via powershell script and IIS management objects until it is up and running for good.